# What is the OpenSSL equivalent of this given C# hashing code?

Tags: bash, openssl, c#, hashing

I've got C# server code which verifies a hash using the following logic. I have no control over the server code and cannot change it.

```
string key = "xZBn34L4myg[...]cebvr7A==";

var hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 { Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key) };
byte[] hashPayLoad = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoad));  
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashPayLoad);
```

For the message "*message*" the code above calculates `JbE9u3X+bKwYizXNcrWTImjooqg+a4Lh9hj4yQHMoHs=` as the signature.

On the client-side, in a bash script, I'd like to create a message the server should verify, using OpenSSL:

```
signature=$(echo -n "message" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac xZBn34L4myg[...]cebvr7A== -binary | base64)
```

The result of this operation is a signature of `bFHvntwvCI6eJqTdoyryxgtPSwyUw/+a79rSvvKs5vE=`.

This differs from the server version. The reason for this is that the server is using `Convert.FromBase64String()` to get the key's bytes, but OpenSSL interpreting the "-hmac" parameter differently. If I had control over the server, I could change it to `Key = UTF8.GetBytes(key)` and would end up with the same hash as the client. But alas, that's not possible.

So my question is: how can I change the bash script in a way that it yields the server's hashing result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot believe it...I found the answer. After hours and hours of trying!

OpenSSL is treating the input key string as binary data. The server however, interprets it as base64 encoded data, decodes it and uses the resulting bytes as the key.

This means, the client has to also treat the key as base64 and decode it. This can be done using:

```
echo -n "xZBn34L4myg[...]cebvr7A==" | base64 --decode > key.dat
```

The command will write the decoded data into a file.

The interesting bit is now that the file content can be passed to openssl and apparently it doesn't complain about potentially non-printable characters:

```
echo -n "message" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$(<./key.dat)" -binary | base64
```

Alternatively, it can also be achieved without the file detour:

```
hashedSignature=$(echo -n "message" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$(echo -n "xZBn34L4myg[...]cebvr7A==" | base64 --decode)" -binary | base64)
```

As per comment from @user1686, the solution above might be problematic:

> Remember that command-line arguments are C null-terminated strings, so
>   you'd better make sure that the -hmac key does not have any 0x00 bytes
>   or it'll get truncated at that point. Use -macopt hexkey: to avoid
>   this problem

To overcome this, here's a version using a hex key:

```
hashedSignature=$(echo -n "message" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$(echo -n "xZBn34L4myg[...]cebvr7A==" | base64 --decode | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"') -binary | base64)
```

This is not becoming more readable, I must say :-)
I presume, the issue with 0x00 bytes would also apply to the file-based solution.

All will generate the expected hash of `JbE9u3X+bKwYizXNcrWTImjooqg+a4Lh9hj4yQHMoHs=`

Comment: Remember that command-line arguments are C null-terminated strings, so you'd better make sure that the -hmac key does not have any 0x00 bytes or it'll get truncated at that point. Use `-macopt hexkey:` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Good point. Can you provide an example what the command should look like? This does not work: `hashedSignature=$(echo -n "message" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:$(echo -n xZBn34L4myg[...]cebvr7A== | base64 --decode) -binary | base64)`

Comment: Well, hexkey needs to be encoded to hexadecimal... (as in `xxd -p` or `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"'`)